# Facebook PHP SDK 3.x , sometimes doesnt give me the User ID

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Hey im developing a fb canvas application, and this application is like a control panel, that if you click a button you go to other section of the app,etc,etc ,

i use the user id of facebook, to determine if the user can use the application, because is just for a few people , so my problem is that facebook sometimes gives me the user id and sometimes not,  i use this simple code

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  'cookie' => true,

));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user){ $auth=true; }else{ $auth=false; }
```

this code is inside a "config.php" that i include in every file, and then i use the $auth to determine if the user can see the information i want, and it works always in the main page, but sometime when i jump to other page of the app (that includes aswell the config.php), it doesnt give me the userId, and the strange part is that sometimes it does

i tried to store this in a session, but i realized that when it not show the userid, there isnt any session too :S

Answer (score 0):

edit: Sorry, I did not notice you're developing a canvas app. I'm however leaving this here, to tell you that fetching the userid is not enough.

The easiest way to handle the Facebook authentication is probably to integrate the [JS-lib and a login-button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) on your website. The php SDK will "automagically" recognize the auth session then, so that you don't have to :)

On another note, using the ID is not enough to authenticate users. You should fetch `me` using the graph API to make absolutely sure user has authenticated your app:

```
try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //Not authenticated
}
```